# Intellij idea code completion for w3.css framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intellij-idea, w3.css

I'm using w3.css framework from https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp which is an alternative to Bootstrap.
IntelliJ idea does not show up code completion for this framework.

**Does anyone know how to set it up in IntelliJ idea?**

I did add the link to the head of page also but still no result.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <title>W3.CSS framework</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try downloading the library locally per instructions in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/style-sheets.html#ws_html_code_completion?

[image]

Once you do this, completion should be there:

[image]